# Can you capture YouTube Play events in Galleria?

Tags: youtube-api, galleria

I'd like to track when the user clicks Play on a Youtube video in a Galleria slideshow, for tracking in Google Analytics.

As far as I can tell, Galleria creates an iframe with the src attribute set to your video URL, and not using the [YouTube Iframe API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference), which allows you to listen to events.

So the only way I can think of doing it is implementing a plugin or modifying the Galleria video methods to use the Youtube Iframe API. Unless there's another way (or someone has already done this)?

Comment: Or maybe I could fake it by just listening for the first click on the stage, and assuming it was on the play button..

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using [Jquery iframeTracker](https://github.com/finalclap/iframeTracker-jquery) to listen for the first click on an iframe, like so:

```js
global.video_clicked = false;
    Galleria.ready(function () {
        this.bind("loadfinish", function (e) {
            //Video Plays: Capture the first click anywhere inside the iframe for Google Analytics
            global.video_clicked = false;
            $('.galleria-image iframe').iframeTracker({
                blurCallback: function(){
                    if (!global.video_clicked) {
                        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Video', 'play', $('.galleria-info-title').text()]);   
                        global.video_clicked = true;
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```